# LTL Formula with Aorai

Tags: frama-c

I am trying to find an example about the LTL operator _ F_ which means fatally with Aorai but i can't figure out exactly what this operator aims and there are no examples in the repository "tests" of Aorai
For example, i wrote this formula

```
CALL(main) && _X_ (CALL(a) && _X_(RETURN(a) && _F_ (RETURN(b) && _X_ (RETURN(main)) ) ))
```

which says that in my program main, i have to call the function a() and after this i don't understand what happens with the operator fatally but it seems that it takes and accepts whatever we call after the function a() with no warning or error from Aorai. If anybody could help me or could give a right example about it.
For example, i have this program below which i would like to test with this formula above

```
void a() 
{}
void b() 
{}
int main() 
{ a();
  a();
  b();
  b();
  a();
  return 0;}
```

I type `frama-c -aorai-ltl test.ltl test.c`
Normally, there should be an error or warning from Aorai. No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is more about temporal logic than Frama-C/Aorai itself, but the meaning of this formula is that `main` must call `a`, then do whatever it wants, before calling  `b` and returning just after that.

NB: note that Aorai only traces call and return events, so that e.g. "just after" here means that `main` cannot not call any function after its last call to `b`, but can still perform some actions, such as `x++;`.

**Update**
I've run your complete example on Frama-C. Indeed a post-condition is missing in the contract for `main` generated by Aorai, namely that the state of the generated automaton at the end of `main` (`T0_S4`) is supposed to be accepting, which is not the case here. This is a bug. If you write explicitely an equivalent automaton in the `ya` language, as

```
%init: S0;
%accept: Sf;

S0: { CALL(main) } -> S1;

S1: { [ a() ] } -> S2;

S2: { RETURN(b) } -> S3
  | other -> S2;

S3: { RETURN(main) } -> Sf;

Sf: -> Sf;
```

Then the generated contract for `main` contains a `requires \false;`, which indeed indicates that the function is not conforming to the automaton, and Aoraï warns about that.

Please note however that in the general case, Aoraï will not emit any warning. It generates contracts that, if fulfilled, imply that the whole program is conforming to the automaton. The proof of the contract must be done by another plugin (e.g. WP or Value Analysis)

Comment: Sorry about it but i don't know exactly where i have to ask this question. I have understood that we have to call a and i can call whatever i want after this but the matter is exactly when i call b with this formula , normally after it , i could not call any function otherwise there will be an error and it is not the case, i called others functions after b and Aorai did not report any error ... I use frama-c  Sodium-20150201. Is it already implemented on this version? May be it is a bug....

Comment: If your question is about the analysis of a specific program with Aoraï, then in order to help you, we need said program and the exact command line that you used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for your time, i noticed what you mean about the post-condition (main)